# Matrix version of number theoretic  integral lattice claim

Tags: nt.number-theory, quadratic-forms

I know this not, everybody else seems to. This is from page 215 of Cassels, Rational Quadratic Forms, formula 4.1, or SPLAG, page 389 formula (36). quote:

> If $f$ and $g$ are forms of
>   determinant $d$ in the same genus,
>   then they are rationally equivalent by
>   some transformation whose denominator
>   is prime to $2d.$ Hence we can find
>   corresponding lattices $L,M$ for which
>   $$ [ L : L \cap M ] = [ M : L \cap M]
> > = r,    $$ say, for some number $r$ which is prime to $2d.$

We are talking about Siegel's definition of forms being in the same genus if they are **rationally equivalent without essential denominator.**

So, here is an example in matrix slang. Given quadratic forms with symmetric matrices
$$ F \; = \;  
 \left(  \begin{array}{cccc}
 2 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\\
 1 & 2  & 0 & 0 \\\
 0 & 0 & 2  & 1  \\\ 
 1 & 0 & 1  & 6  
\end{array} 
  \right)
  $$
and
$$ G \; = \;  
 \left(  \begin{array}{cccc}
 2 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\\
 1 & 2  & 0 & 1 \\\
 1 & 0 & 2  & 0  \\\ 
 0 & 1 & 0  & 8  
\end{array} 
  \right)
  $$
Next, I take $r=3,$ because the discriminant is $29,$ and find
$$ P \; = \;  
 \left(  \begin{array}{cccc}
 1 & 1 & 1 & 7 \\\
 1 & -2  & 1 & -5 \\\
 1 & 1 & -2  & 1  \\\ 
 1 & 1 & 1  & -2  
\end{array} 
  \right)
  $$
that satisfies
$$  P^T \; F \; P \; = \; 9 \; G  = r^2 \; G.  $$

Now, here is the trick. To get back from $G$ to $F,$ it appears that one needs to use $Q = \; \mbox{adj} \; P$ which has a much larger determinant, so things look asymmetric. Indeed,
$$ Q \; = \; \; \mbox{adj} \; P \; = \;  
 \left(  \begin{array}{cccc}
 -18 & -27 & -27 & -9 \\\
 9 & 27  & 0 & -36 \\\
 -9 & 0 & 27  & -18  \\\ 
 -9 & 0 & 0  & 9  
\end{array} 
  \right)
  $$
However, a miracle! The GCD of these entries is 9, and we get the improved
$$ Q_1 \; = \;   
 \left(  \begin{array}{cccc}
 -2 & -3 & -3 & -1 \\\
 1 & 3  & 0 & -4 \\\
 -1 & 0 & 3  & -2  \\\ 
 -1 & 0 & 0  & 1  
\end{array} 
  \right).
  $$
The we really do get what we wanted,
$$  P Q_1 = -9 I = \pm r^2 I $$
and
$$ Q_1^T \; G \; Q_1 \; = \; 9 \; F = \; r^2 F.    $$

Alright, so here is the **question,** with the dimension $n$ thrown in: Suppose $F,G$ are symmetric positive definite matrices of integers with the same determinant $d.$ Suppose we have an integer $r$ with $\gcd (r, 2 d) = 1.$ Suppose that we have a matrix $P$ of integers, with $\det P = \pm r^n,$ such that $  P^T \; F \; P \; = \; r^2 \; G.    $ Take $Q = \; \mbox{adj} \; P,$ so that $\det Q = \pm r^{n^2 - n}$ and $PQ = QP = (\det P) I = \pm r^n I.$ Is it always the case that
$$  \gcd Q = r^{n-2}  ?$$

I think this is progress. Since 1994, it is only 18 years that I have been completely confused on this point and unaware that I was confused.

EDIT:
The matrix $P$ is not necessarily rank $1 \pmod r.$ Here are the two forms by Schiemann of discriminant 1729, not equivalent but in the same genus and, wait for it, the same theta series.

$$ F \; = \;  
 \left(  \begin{array}{cccc}
 4 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\\
 1 & 8  & 1 & 3 \\\
 0 & 1 & 8  & 4  \\\ 
 1 & 3 & 4  & 10  
\end{array} 
  \right)
  $$
and
$$ G \; = \;  
 \left(  \begin{array}{cccc}
 4 & 2 & 1 & 1 \\\
 2 & 8  & -2 & 1 \\\
 1 & -2 & 10  & 5  \\\ 
 1 & 1 & 5  & 10  
\end{array} 
  \right)
  $$
Next, I take $r=5,$ and find
$$ P \; = \;  
 \left(  \begin{array}{cccc}
 -1 & 6 & -4 & 0 \\\
 -2 & -3  & -3 & 0 \\\
 3 & 2 & -3  & 0  \\\
 -1 & -1 & 0  & -5  
\end{array} 
  \right)
  $$
that satisfies
$$  P^T \; F \; P \; = \; 25 \; G  = r^2 \; G.  $$
We still wind up, in the same manner, with a very pleasant
$$ Q_1 \; = \;   
 \left(  \begin{array}{cccc}
 -3 & -2 & 6 & 0 \\\
 3 & -3  & -1 & 0 \\\
 -1 & -4 & -3  & 0  \\\ 
 0 & 1 & -1  & -5  
\end{array} 
  \right).
  $$

Comment: Here is an idea where I haven't filled in the details: Take a look at http://mathoverflow.net/questions/97151/integer-matrices-with-a-strange-divisibility-property . You want to know when a matrix $P$ will have the property that all $(n-2) \times (n-2)$ minors are divisible by $r^{n-2}$. I point out that one good explanation is if $P \mod r$ has rank $1$. That's true in your example; is it always true?

Comment: @David, thanks, I will look. I think it is all $(n-1) \times (n-1)$ minors. The rank 1 thing may be true, I need to think. I have little objection to $r$ being prime for the moment, it may ease things. 

Comment: Whoops, $(n-1) \times (n-1)$ minors is right, thanks.

Comment: @David, rank 1 is too strong a statement, I edited in Schiemann's quaternary forms. We still get the nice condition on the adjoint, though. This is all Watson's sort of thinking, I cannot seem to find quite this. And, it may have been known to Minkowski. I wasn't there at the time.

Comment: Gotcha. I'll think a bit about this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Write $P$ in Smith normal form as $SDT$, where $S$ and $T$ have determinant $\pm 1$ and $D$ is diagonal with diagonal entries $d_1 | d_2 | d_3 | \cdots | d_n$. We may replace $(F, G, P)$ by $(S^{-T} F S^{-1}, T^{T} G T, D)$ and therefore assume $P$ is diagonal with entries $d_i$ as stated. Note that this replacement preserves all the hypotheses and the desired conclusion.

**Claim 1:**  We have $r^2 | d_k d_{n+1-k}$ for all $1 \leq k \leq n$.

**Proof:** Suppose, to the contrary, that $p$ is a prime dividing $r^2$ more times than it divides $d_k d_{n+1-k}$. The condition $D^T F D \equiv 0 \mod r^2$ means $d_i d_j F_{ij} \equiv 0 \mod r^2$ for all $(i,j)$. So, for all $i \leq k$ and $j \leq n+1-k$, we have $F_{ij} \equiv 0 \mod p$. So the first $k$ rows of $F$ span a $\leq k-1$ dimensional space modulo $p$, contradicting that $p$ does not divide $\det F$. $\square$

Claim 1 is used only to prove the stronger:

**Claim 2:**  For all $1 \leq k \leq n$, we have $d_k d_{n+1-k} = r^2$.

**Proof:** Since $D^T F D = r^2 G$ and $\det F= \det G$, we deduce that $\det D = r^n$. So $\prod_{k=1}^n d_k = r^n$ and $\prod (d_k d_{n+1-k}/ r^2) = 1$. By the previous claim, all of the factors in this product are positive integers, so they must all be $1$. $\square$

In particular, every $d_k | r^2$. This means that every principal minor $\det D/d_k$ must be divisible by $r^n/r^2 = r^{n-2}$, and the nonprincipal minors are zero, giving the desired conclusion. More conceptually, if we define $D'$ to be $D$ with the elements in the opposite order, then $D D' = r^2$. Conjugating back to the original basis, this $D'$ will turn into the matrix you called $Q_1$.

Comment: Printed out to study with my little brain. You know, if nobody has told you, you are really quite good at this, you ought to consider a career in mathematics.

Comment: Please excuse Will, sometimes he is slow on the uptake.  Only the other day I was reading a post of his about an idea
on propulsion he was considering: the selfmobile.  Gerhard "Not Always Faster Than Will" Paseman, 2012.05.30

Comment: @Gerhard, now I must leave it in place. I know where David works. Right, I get a little typing difference with inverses or not for $S,T$ but no matter. That is a new one on me, if we have a square matrix over a field  with a rectangular $a \times b$ block of nothing but $0'$s, and $a + b \geq n+1,$ the the matrix is singular. Very nice. 

Comment: @Gerhard, I still think the selfmobile has a future, I just need some venture capital.

Comment: Will, the observation two comments up can be understood in terms of Hall's Marriage Theorem. 

Comment: Alright, for prime $p | r,$ the rank of $D'$ and $D$ are the same $\pmod p,$ so the same applies to $P$ and $Q_1.$ I think that is the final piece of the puzzle.

Comment: @Gerry, I looked up Hall's Marriage Theorem but cannot fill in the argument. 

Comment: Will, a row for each man, a column for each woman, a zero for each incompatible couple. There's a set of $a$ men with at most $n-b$ compatible women, and $a+b\ge n+1$ implies $a\gt n-b$, so there is no pairing off of men with women that doesn't involve an incompatible couple. So there is no term in the determinant without a zero. 

Comment: @Gerry, thanks, I did wonder if it were a sort of extended pigeonhole argument.

Answer (score 1):

A much shorter proof, though one that doesn't explain as much to me. From $P^T F P = r^2 G$, we deduce $P^{-1} = r^{-2} G^{-1} P^T F$ and thus $P^{-1} \in \frac{1}{r^2 \det G} \mathrm{Mat}(\mathbb{Z})$. But also $P^{-1} = \frac{1}{\det P} \mathrm{Adj}(P)$ so $P^{-1} \in \frac{1}{r^n} \mathrm{Mat}(\mathbb{Z})$. Since $GCD(r^2 \det G, r^n) = r^2$, we have $P^{-1} \in \frac{1}{r^2} \mathrm{Mat}(\mathbb{Z})$, as desired.

Comment: Thanks again, David. I think I am getting somewhere. If the rank of $P \pmod r$ is $w,$ then i get that $ [ L : L \cap M] = r^{n-w}$ as long as $r$ is prime, anyway. 